# Sorting in Angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am building an app using Angular.
I have JSON that comes back from the server sorted by date.
I bind to this data in the view.

A user may change what data is displayed in the view. This kicks off a request and the view gets updated as it is bound to the JSON data changes.

When Angular gets this JSON data it then sorts it alphabetically.
I want to maintain the sort order that comes from the server.

I googled this a bit and found the following solution...

```
<div ng-repeat="key in notSorted(myData)" ng-init="data = myData[key]">
```

"notSorted" is a function on the controller...

```
$scope.notSorted = function(obj){
    if (!obj) {
        return [];
    }
    return Object.keys(obj);
}
```

This works fine initially. The data displays in the correct order. 
However it breaks the binding. So when the user tries to change the data being displayed, the view does not get updated as notSorted does not see the binding change.

I can think of a few hacky ways around this such as manually firing the updates but I would like to do this the correct angular way.
Anyone know what that is?

Thanks

Comment: If you want order in JavaScript, use an array, not an object.

Comment: I think angular does not change Order that comes from server, there might be some other issue check again the array returned from server. see array log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the way the data was coming back from the server and how I needed to iterate over that data I wasn't able to get any of the "orderBy" or filter solutions to work. 
However I discovered that in Angular 1.4 they removed the default ordering (alphabetical/ascending) in favour of preserving the order the data was returned from the server...

http://jaxenter.com/angular-releases-1-3-update-1-4-beta-113906.html

I was using 1.3.x and simply updated to 1.4 and it worked OOTB.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I believe you need this: 
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy

It works sort of like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy:'key'">
```

Comment: Hi sEver, thanks for the reply. I'm not sure this will work for me. I would need to convert the JSON object to an array to use 'orderBy' but I would need it to be an associative array to preserve the keys as I also display the key in the view